Is it true that the map $f_{n+1}'$ always injective?
If I have a map $f_{n+1}: A_{n+1} \to A_n,$ can I always say that the map $$f_{n+1}': A_{n+1}/\operatorname{ker}f_{n+1} \to A_n$$ is always injective?

How do you define $f_{n+1}'$? What is its kernel?

@azif00 I do not know, I just meant that if we moded out by the kernel we always get an injective map, probably I should not have changed the name, right?

You cannot change the domain of the function without changing the function. When you change the domain you get a different function. You need to define it.

how can I define it? Can I say that its kernel equal to the kernel of the first function? So that I can get the injectivity?@azif00

I assume your $A_n$ is some sort of algebraic structure (group, ring, algebra etc.) and $f_n$ is a homomorphism of such structures. Then, in short, $\textbf{yes}$. $f_n$ always induces an injective homomorphism, call it $\overline{f_n}$, from $A_n/\operatorname{ker}(f_n)$ to $A_{n-1}$. Many will, by abuse of notation, simply use $f_n$ for $\overline{f_n}$, since the action of $\overline{f_n}$ on equivalence classes is simply the action of $f_n$ on any element of such a class.

What about the kernel of the new map, what is it as was asked in the comments above?

I sort of gave the definition of $\overline{f_n}:A_n/\ker(f_n)\to A_{n-1}$ already: it is given by $\overline{f_n}([a]) = f_n(a)$. Thus, its kernel is trivial.
